# How to get each successive number for a given number passed to a method?

Tags: ruby

Sorry if the question is hard to understand. **Let me clarify by example.** Suppose I have a method, which gives me `each` successive number up to the number given `max`.

```
def numbers(max)
   max.each do |n|
     puts n
   end
end

numbers(10)
#=> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

I know I can use a range `1..10` but that is not what I want. I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a range?

Comment: I didn't realize I could use `range` the way you showed in your answer. Thank you for clarifying. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `upto`:

```
def numbers(max)
    1.upto(max) do |n|
        # do stuff with n
    end
end
```

Also, why don't you want to use a range? This works just fine:

```
def numbers(max)
    (1..max).each do |n|
        # stuff
    end
end
```